# Reference-request: Closed form of $\int_0^1 (1-W_{-1}(-t/e))^x-(1-W_0(-t/e))^x\,dt$

Tags: integration, reference-request, gamma-function, lambert-w

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$

$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}\def\erf{\operatorname{erf}}\def\Ei{\operatorname{Ei}}$

For $x\in\mathbb R,\ x\ne-1$

\begin{align}
I(x)&=
\int_0^1 
(1-\Wm(-\tfrac t\e))^x 
-
(1-\Wp(-\tfrac t\e))^x 
\, dt 
\tag{1}\label{1}
\\
&=
\frac{\e\,(2+\e\,(x-1)\,\Gamma(x+2,1))}{x+1}
=f(x)
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

where $\Wp,\ \Wm$ are the real branches 
of the Lambert $\W$ function, 
and $\Gamma$ is 
the incomplete gamma function.

For integer values $x=n$, $I(n)$ follows the pattern
of $\e\cdot a_n$ from[A093964](http://oeis.org/A093964).

\begin{align}
I(1)&=f(1)=\e
,\\
I(2)&=f(2)=6\,\e
,\\
I(3)&=f(3)=33\,\e
,\\
&\dots
\end{align}

Some other special cases of $x$:

\begin{align}
I(\tfrac12)&=
\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-\Wm(-\tfrac t\e)} \, dt
-
\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-\Wp(-\tfrac t\e)} \, dt
\\
&=
(\tfrac32\,\sqrt2+\tfrac14\,\e^2\,\sqrt\pi\,(\erf(\sqrt2)-1))
\\
&-(\tfrac32\,\sqrt2-\tfrac12\,\e
+\tfrac14\,\e^2\,\sqrt\pi\,(\erf(\sqrt2)-\erf(1)))
\\
&=
\tfrac12\,\e+\tfrac14\,\e^2\,\sqrt\pi\,(\erf(1)-1)
=f(\tfrac12)
\tag{3}\label{3}
\\
&\approx 0.844113386646
,\\
I(-2)&=
\int_0^1 \frac1{(1-\Wm(-\tfrac t\e))^2}
-
\frac1{(1-\Wp(-\tfrac t\e))^2} \, dt
\\
&\approx -.57344306156
\\
&=
\e\,(3\,\e\,\Ei(1,1)-2)
=f(-2)
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}
where $\Ei(a,x) = x^{a-1} \Gamma(1-a,x)$.

\begin{align}
I(-\Omega)
&\approx -0.4015641473638446
\approx f(-\Omega)
,\quad \Omega=\W(1)\approx .56714329
.
\end{align}

Also,

\begin{align}
I(-1)&\approx -0.523798568446
\\
&\approx \e\,(1-2\,\e\,\Ei(1,1))=\lim_{x\to -1}f(x)
.
\end{align}

Questions:

1) Is this correct/known? Any reference/confirmation?

2) Is it possible to transform \eqref{2} 
in order to cure the nasty case of $x=-1$?

$\endgroup$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By simple change of variables, we have
$$
 - \int_0^1 {\left( {1 - W_0 \left( { - \frac{t}{e}} \right)} \right)^x dt}  = \int_0^1 {(1 + s)^x e^{1 - s} (s - 1)ds} 
$$
and
$$
\int_0^1 {\left( {1 - W_{ - 1} \left( { - \frac{t}{e}} \right)} \right)^x dt}  = \int_1^{ + \infty } {(1 + s)^x e^{1 - s} (s - 1)ds} .
$$
Consequently,
$$
I(x) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {(1 + s)^x e^{1 - s} (s - 1)ds}  = e\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - s} s}}{{(1 + s)^{ - x} }}ds}  - e\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - s} }}{{(1 + s)^{ - x} }}ds} 
\\
 = e\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - s} }}{{(1 + s)^{ - x - 1} }}ds}  - 2e\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - s} }}{{(1 + s)^{ - x} }}ds}  = e^2 \Gamma (x + 2,1) - 2e^2 \Gamma (x + 1,1)
\\
 = e^2 \Gamma (x + 2,1) - 2e^2 \frac{{\Gamma (x + 2,1) - e^{ - 1} }}{{x + 1}} = e\frac{{2 + e(x - 1)\Gamma (x + 2,1)}}{{x + 1}}.
$$
Regarding your second question, you may write
$$
I(x) = e^2 \Gamma (x + 2,1) - 2e^2 \Gamma (x + 1,1) = e(e(x - 1)\Gamma (x + 1,1) + 1).
$$

Comment: Impressive solution

Comment: I'm not sure why did you move the $(1+s)^{x}$ in the denominator when you found $I(x)$, perhaps more cleaner: 
$$\int_0^\infty (s+1)^x (s-1)e^{1 - s}ds\overset{s+1=u}=e^2\int_1^\infty u^{x}(u-2)e^{-u}du=e^2\left(\Gamma(x+2,1)-2\Gamma(x+1,1\right)$$
Where we used $\Gamma(z,x)=\int_x^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t}dt$.
Anyway I like this answer, fwiw the result can also be written as $e\lfloor e \cdot\Gamma (x+1)\rfloor-2e\lfloor e \cdot\Gamma (x+1)\rfloor$ using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Special_values).

Comment: The reason I wrote it like that is to make it similar to http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.6.E5

Comment: Ah, I understand then. I assumed the definiton from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Definition) for the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: You ment $e\left\lfloor {e\Gamma (x + 2)} \right\rfloor  - 2e\left\lfloor {e\Gamma (x + 1)} \right\rfloor$ provided $x$ is a positive integer.